# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::guard()

Tags: php, laravel

Got this error, but I suspect it is the way I'm trying to call `customers` guard. How do I call it with `$this->auth` instead of all `Auth::guard` examples I have seen?

```
    if ($this->auth::guard('customers')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true) === false) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->with(['message' => 'Your username/password combination was incorrect', 'failed' => true])
            ->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: if my answer work for you, can you mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$this->auth::guard('customers')
```

to

```
\Auth::guard('customers')
```

or

```
auth()->guard('customers')
```